Semantic error TS2786: 'Popover' cannot be used as a JSX component
The project was created with tsdx, rollup and storybook
A popover component was created using the react-tiny-popover library, it works correctly when running storybook, when running the tsdx build it gives the following error:
(typescript) Error: my-new-project/src/components/Popover/PopoverComponent.tsx(5,12): semantic error TS2786: 'Popover' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
Error: my-new-project/src/components/Popover/PopoverComponent.tsx(5,12): semantic error TS2786: 'Popover' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

follows the implementation of the Popover component:
export interface PopoverProps {
  label: ReactNode | string;
  children: ReactNode | string;
  className?: string;
  classNamePanel?: string;
  containerClassName?: string;
  positions?: PopoverPosition;
  isCloseClickElement?: boolean;
}

export const Popover: React.FC<PopoverProps> = ({
  children,
  className = '',
  containerClassName = '',
  label,
  positions = 'bottom',
  isCloseClickElement,
  classNamePanel = '',
}) => {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setIsPopoverOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div className={`food2c-popover ${className}`}>
      <PopoverComponent
        containerStyle={{
          padding: '12px',
        }}
        positions={positions}
        isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
        reposition={false}
        onClickOutside={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          setIsPopoverOpen(false);
        }}
        containerClassName={containerClassName}
        content={() => (
          <div className={`food2c-popover-panel ${classNamePanel}`}>
            <Paper
              onClickPaper={() =>
                isCloseClickElement ? setIsPopoverOpen(false) : null
              }
            >
              {children}
            </Paper>
          </div>
        )}
      >
        <button
          className="food2c-popover-button"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setIsPopoverOpen(!isPopoverOpen);
          }}
        >
          {label}
        </button>
      </PopoverComponent>
    </div>
  );
};



import React from 'react';
import { PopoverProps, Popover } from 'react-tiny-popover';

export const PopoverComponent: React.FC<PopoverProps> = props => {
  return (<Popover {...props}>{props.children}</Popover>) as JSX.Element;
};

rollup.config.js
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  plugins: [
    sass({
      insert: true,
      output: 'dist/bundle.css',
    }),
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
    }),
  ],
};

tsdx.config.js
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const svgr = require('@svgr/rollup');

module.exports = {
  rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      postcss({
        plugins: [autoprefixer, cssnano],
        inject: false,
        extract: 'bundle.css',
      }),
      svgr()
    );

    return config;
  },
};

tsconfig.json

{
  // see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig to better understand tsconfigs
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
  }
}

